# Surveymokey create response with image/file

Tags: surveymonkey

We are using surveymonkey for quizes. I need to test our etl pipelines. So need to generate response. I use:

```
https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/collectors/{id}/responses
```

and post a response with answers:

```
"pages": [
        {
            "id": "179557239",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "id": "713464009",
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "choice_id": "4692710728"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

However some of questions suppose file upload. I do not understand how to do it via post request